# How to use Javascript in UIWebView?

Tags: javascript, objective-c, uiwebview

Could you guys recommend me some books or live examples of implementing Javascript in UIWebView or Objective-C? I’m a beginner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this method to use JavaScript on a UIWebView :

```
- (NSString *)stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:(NSString *)script
```

You can read more [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).